# unity - Ubuntu 16.04 no menu bar, launcher, top bar, dash, window borders disappeared

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I know this question has been answered many times. But nothing works for me!!!
I created a new user "moe" and low and behold everything is working in moe's window, but not in my original window.
Since things are working properly in moe's window how do I transfer the functionality to the original window.
Hopefully this will click with someone and a working answer will appear in my e-mail, keeping fingers crossed!
VERY Frustrated user!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer:

```
cd .cache
mv compizconfig-1 compizconfig-1_renamed
```

and reboot. You lose your Desktop settings, but you get back your Desktop.

Comment: Had the same problem today after running an upgrade. Many thanks, that was the only solution to my issue after trying many other fixes ! Should be accepted as answer